# LVM lvdisplay - what's with the less-than sign?

Tags: debian, lvm

If I display the size of my root filesystem (a logical volume) with `df` I see that it's just over 6GB:

```
df -h /
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg01-root  137G  6.2G  124G   5% /
```

But if I ask LVM to tell me about it it can't work out the size and gives me an utterly useless estimate:

```
lvdisplay vg01/root
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg01/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vg01
  ... snip
  LV Size                <139.70 GiB
  ... etc
```

Why does this happen?  Is there any way that I can circumvent it within a shell script which needs to know the size of the LV?  `df` won't work if the LV isn't mounted.

This is Debian 10 unstable, if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<` in the `lvdisplay` output simply means the size was rounded. By default all LVM commands print "human readable" sizes and if the size can't be precise on two decimal places, it will be rounded, which is indicated by the less-than sign. If you want exact number, you can specify unit manually, the most precise will always be `--units=B` for bytes.

Note that `lvdisplay` prints size of the LV (block device), not the filesystem which can have different size. If you want to see size of an unmounted filesystem, you need to use filesystem specific tools, like `dumpe2fs` for Ext.

Also your root filesystem is not 6 GB, it's 137 GB according to `df`, 6 GB is used size.

Comment: Ugh; I'm an idiot.  Of course I should have noticed that it's telling me the allocated size; the approximate value is approximately right ...  Thank you for taking the time to help me.